# ng-repeat orderBy only changing once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a table with Angular that has headers that can set the order, so far it's working but it only sets the order once.

I have used console.log and the variable is changing.

Table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="setOrder('iss.issueID')"> ID</th>
            <th ng-click="setOrder('iss.issueTitle')" >Issue</th>
            <th ng-click="setOrder('iss.zone')">Zone</th>
            <th ng-click="setOrder('iss.type')">Type</th>
            <th ng-click="setOrder('iss.time')">Time</th>
            <th ng-click="setOrder('iss.userID')">User ID</th>
            <th ng-click="setOrder('iss.user')">User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat= "iss in issues | filter:name | orderBy:order">
            <td>{{ iss.issueID }}</td>
            <td>{{ iss.issueTitle }}</td>
            <td>{{ iss.zone }}</td>
            <td>{{ iss.type }}</td>
            <td>{{iss.time * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '}}</td>
            <td>{{ iss.userID }}</td>
            <td>{{ iss.user }}</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Function

```
$scope.issues = [

    <? php

         $result = mysqli_query($con, $qr);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

             echo "{issueID: '".$row['issueID']."', 
                 user: '".$row['firstName'].' '.$row['lastName']."', 
                 userID: '".$row['userID']."',
                 issueTitle: '".$row['issue']."', 
                 issueDesc: '".$row['issueDesc']."', 
                 time: '".$row['timeReceived']."',
                 machine: '".$row['machineID'].' '.$row['manufacturer'].' '.$row['machineType']."',
                 zone: '".$row['zoneID'].' '.$row['Location'].' '.$row['Name']."',
                 type: '".$row['type']."',
                 technician: '".$row['techID']." ".$row['tfirstName']." ".$row['tlastName']."'";
             echo "},";
         }

     ?> 
];

$scope.setOrder = function (order) {
    $scope.order = order;
    console.log($scope.order = order);
};
});
```

Comment: Give us a sample of the `issues` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong value to the `setOrder` function.

You should remove the `iss.` part. You only need the actual key names of the object.

```
<tr>
    <th ng-click="setOrder('issueID')"> ID</th>
    <th ng-click="setOrder('issueTitle')" >Issue</th>
    <th ng-click="setOrder('zone')">Zone</th>
    <th ng-click="setOrder('type')">Type</th>
    <th ng-click="setOrder('time')">Time</th>
    <th ng-click="setOrder('userID')">User ID</th>
    <th ng-click="setOrder('user')">User</th>
</tr>
```

Demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/Afh8ha5F7zBgGa2CaO4o?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, obvious now, thanks for getting me back on track!

Comment: Also, you should note that you iss variable is defined (as part of ngRepeat) in the <tr> of the bottom row and will be available inside that tag only. So you cannot use it any where else except the <tr> it was defined in.